# search a dataframe from a list and add coloumn to say found or not

Tags: scala, dataframe

this is my df with 2 coloumns:

```
utid|description
12342|my name is 123 amrud and nitesh
2345|my name is anil
2122|my name is 1234 mohan
```

and a list like list `{"mohan","nitesh"}`
need to search if a elemnet from this list is present in the description coloumn ..if yes then print "found" else print "not found " in a different coloumn of the dataframe.the output df should be somewhat like below:
the list is far bigger than this of around 20k elements ..
the output dataframe should be like below

```
utid|description|foundornot
12342|my name is 123 amrud and nitesh|found
2345|my name is xyz |not found
2122|my name is 1234 mohan|found
```

Any help is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define a `udf` function *check for the condition* and return on of the `found` or `not found` strings

```
val list = List("mohan","nitesh")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def checkUdf = udf((strCol: String) => if (list.exists(strCol.contains)) "found" else "not found")

df.withColumn("foundornot", checkUdf(col("description"))).show(false)
```

Thats it and you should be getting

```
+-----+-------------------------------+----------+
|utid |description                    |foundornot|
+-----+-------------------------------+----------+
|12342|my name is 123 amrud and nitesh|found     |
|2345 |my name is anil                |not found |
|2122 |my name is 1234 mohan          |found     |
+-----+-------------------------------+----------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: if in the foundornot coloumn, i need to print the names that were found ..how would we achieve that ....also there could be a possibiloity of multiple names being found ..in taht case the names should be | separated..like nitesh|mohan ..can you please help with this

Comment: i have asked a different question..can you please help me there